# Why does heroku local:run wants to use the global python installation instead of the currently activated virtual env?

Tags: python, heroku, virtualenv, pythonpath

Using Heroku to deploy our Django application, everything seems to work by the spec, except the `heroku local:run` command.

We oftentimes need to run commands through Django's manage.py file. Running them on the **remote**, as one-off dynos, works flawlessly.
To run them **locally**, we try:

```
heroku local:run python manage.py the_command
```

Which fails, despite the fact that the current virtual env contains a Django installation, with

```
 ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

### Diagnostic through the python path

Then `heroku local:run which python` returns:

```
 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Whereas `which python` returns:

```
 /Users/myusername/MyProject/venv/bin/python #the correct value
```

---

- Is this a bug in Heroku local:run ? Or are we missunderstanding its expected behaviour ?
- And more importantly: is there a way to have `heroku local:run` use the currently installed virtual env ?

Comment: @johnbachir I see you posted a substantial bounty here looking for more detail. I'm wondering if there is something more you need above and beyond the code walk in my answer?  I'd be happy to take another look if there's an aspect that isn't addressed - wouldn't want that bounty to go to waste :)

Answer (score 12):

After contacting Heroku's support, we understood the problem.

The support confirmed that `heroku local:run` should as expected use the currently active virtual env.

The problem is a local configuration problem, due to our `.bashrc` content: `heroku local:run` sources `.bashrc` (and in our case, this was prepending $PATH with the path to the global Python installation, making it found before the virtual env's). On the other hand, `heroku local` does not source this file. To quote the last message from their support:

> heroku local:run runs the command using bash in interactive mode, which does read your profile, vs heroku local (aliased to heroku local:start) which does not run in interactive mode.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Ad N's answer.  The reason it absolutely insisted on using system Python instead of the virtual environment that it was used from is as follows.

Heroku local:run sources .bashrc which includes a user's PATH and any additions to the default PATH.  This includes the location of system Python, but not necessarily any additional Python interpreters.  It will use whichever Python interpreter is found first, which should rightly be the system Python (otherwise very import things like init and package management don't work correctly, or at all)

The way around this is instead of running it as heroku local:run which sources .bashrc and includes the system Python is to run it as heroku local so that it uses whatever is active in the virtual environment.

Answer (score 2):

Running Heroku locally is documented [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local), however it only talks about using `heroku local`, which the documentation specifies is a synonym for `heroku local:start`

> heroku local is a shorter alternative to heroku local:start which does the same thing.

The [OP's self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34151405/838992) specifies that the Heroku devs have confirmed that if `heroku local` (equivalent to `heroku local:start`) is used, then the local `.bashrc` is not sourced and the virtualenv python is used as expected

If `heroku local:run` is used, then the local machine's `.bashrc` is sourced and ***in the OP's case*** that `.bashrc` prepended the path to the system `python` to `$PATH` and therefore the system install of python was used.

So, the conclusion is that `heroku local:run` should use the virtualenv python, but it *will not* if your `.bashrc` happens to contain commands that would make it use the system version of python (e.g. by putting the path to the system python first in the path variable).

---

#### Detail via code walk

To see the code and understand the detail from that point of view - look at the [Github repository for `heroku-local`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-local), in particular under [`commands`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-local/tree/master/commands).  Here we see that there is one Javascript file for the `run` command and another for the `start` command.  Look inside and you see they look very similar except they call [`forego.run`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-local/blob/master/lib/forego.js#L36) and [`forego.start`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-local/blob/master/lib/forego.js#L25) respectively (note `forego` is using Foreman in Go - [see here](https://github.com/ddollar/forego)).  These in turn call Node.js [`child_process.spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) to spawn the `forego` process, again with either `run` or `start` as arguments respectively.

Following that - [`run.go`](https://github.com/ddollar/forego/blob/master/run.go#L41) defines a [`NewProcess`](https://github.com/ddollar/forego/blob/master/process.go#L17), upon which it invokes `ShellInvocationCommand`, which is platform specific. Finally - we see the root of the issue in [`unix.go` here](https://github.com/ddollar/forego/blob/master/unix.go#L13) where you see that the profile is sourced in `ShellInvocationCommand`.  When using [`start.go`](https://github.com/ddollar/forego/blob/master/start.go), the method to start the process is entirely different, the `profile` is not sourced, so the virtualenv python is used.

Comment: @johnbachir I hope that's the kind of detail that you are looking for - ping me if there's something that doesn't make sense / doesn't apply to your case.

Comment: I think the problem with loading bashrc again is that virtualenvwrapper script is smart and idempotent, and plain old path prepending is not.